# How to center an item with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to center something in my code with flexbox. It works for all other elements, only here something seems to be wrong.
Does anyone have an idea?

```css
.answer {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px gr;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="answer">
  <p>Answer</p>
</section>
```

[This is how it gets displayed in my live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpJ4X.png)

Comment: I added a snippet to your answer. Not sure what you think is wrong here? The word "Answer" is centered horizontally and vertically in your `answer` class.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `body` tag on css to make center on the page

to make horizontal center

```
body {
  display: flex,
  justify-content: center
}
```

or make vertical center

```
body {
  display: flex,
  align-items: center,
  height: 100vh /* This is for full height of your screen */
}
```

or make horizontal and vertical center

```
body {
  display: flex,
  justify-content: center,
  align-items: center,
  height: 100vh
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "Answer" is centered in the box. Are you trying to center the box on the page? In that case, you would need to apply flex styles to the parent. In this case, the body:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.answer {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px gr;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="answer">
  <p>Answer</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px; /*add to remove body margin which always present and makes v-scroll if not removed*/
}
.answer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /*Remove it if their is no other content on page*/
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="answer">
  <p>Answer</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).